# Sublime Text 3 and custom build profiles - unable to close windows

Tags: python, matplotlib, sublimetext3

Python + scipy + matplotlib builds seamlessly in Sublime provided that I don't need to extend my PYTHONPATH. When I alter the path, though, I can no longer use ⌘W to close the plot windows that my code generates. Hardly a critical problem, but seriously annoying. When focused on the plots, the mac header bar shows a "Python" menu with no contents.

To change the path, I set up a custom build profile under "Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Python.sublime-build" with the following text:

```
{
"cmd": ["python2.7", "-u", "$file"],
"selector":"source.python",
"env":{"PYTHONPATH":"/usr/local/lib/python:/Users/myName/Documents/Python"}
}
```

I can't seem to find the default build system for ST3 - there isn't a "defaults" folder as for ST2.

Suggestions?